# Why is my form not being submitted?

Tags: php, forms

I have 2 functions - one generates the form on my main page and the other processes the submitted form. This is the Braintree sandbox API and their method is this: take in user info and submit to Braintree server, BT server returns a payment method nonce to me which I can then use to POST and view the transaction in my sandbox control panel. However, the form isn't being submitted and I'm not sure at what point in the process the whole submission is failing. **NOTE** - I am submitting the form to the same PHP file where the form is located.

I still need help on this...

**ask.php** - This is the page where I call both functions

```
<div>
        <?php 
            fd_bt_form();   
            fd_process_trans();
        ?>
</div>
```

**find-do-for-anspress.php**

```
  $FD_Braintree_Keys = array(

    Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox'),
    Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('A'),
    Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('B'),
    Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('C')

    );   


function fd_bt_form()
{
    $class_bt_token = new Braintree_ClientToken();
    $clientToken = $class_bt_token->generate();

    ?>
    <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
    <script>

        braintree.setup(
        '<?php echo $clientToken ?>',
        'custom', {
          id: 'checkout',
        }); 

    </script>
    <?php   

    echo 
   '<form id="checkout" action="" method="POST">
        <p>
        <label><font size="5">Amount:</font></label>
        <input type="text" size="4" name="amount" id="amount" />
        </p>
        <input data-braintree-name="number" value="378282246310005">
        <br> <br />
        <input data-braintree-name="expiration_month" value="05">
        <input data-braintree-name="expiration_year" value="17">
        <br> <br />
        <input data-braintree-name="cvv" value="531">
        <br> <br />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Pay">           
    </form>';

    echo $_POST["payment_method_nonce"];
    global $bt_nonce;
    $bt_nonce = $_POST["payment_method_nonce"]; 

    return $bt_nonce;
}

function fd_process_trans() {

    $FD_Braintree_Keys;

    $nonce = $_POST["payment_method_nonce"]; 
    $amount = $_POST["amount"];

    $result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
      'amount' => $amount,
      'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce,
      'options' => array(
        'submitForSettlement' => True,
      ),
    ));

    if ($result->success) {
        echo "Success!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Transaction failed.";
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you click Pay button?

Comment: Well the page reloads as if the form is being submitted. Also, the `payment_method_nonce` shows up at the bottom of the page (because I `echo`'d it) with a valid nonce from Braintree's sandbox servers, so I at least know the form is being submitted to Braintree and returning with the nonce.

Comment: That means fd_bt_form() is being called, but where do you call fd_process_trans() from? I don't see that line on your code here

Comment: Wait I don't understand. By that same logic, I'm also not calling `fd_bt_form()` right?? What is calling `fd_bt_form()`??

Comment: You must be calling that function from somewhere, otherwise it won't get executed. You must call a function for it to be executed. But please note I have no knowledge of Braintree sandbox API.

Comment: Well all that you need to know about it I've written in the description. Literally. It's that simple. [You can even look at the simple visual explanation on their site](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/overview#how-it-works).